# Is ST referentialy transparent?

Tags: haskell

Why is `ST` designed to disallow the following code [as shown in the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types)? The article seems to suggest that `ST` effects would leak into another `ST` if this was allowed, but I don't really understand why.

It seems that I cannot run a specific `ST s (STRef s a)`. Are `ST` effects contained and referentially transparent, but such use is still considered invalid?

Intuition tells me that there is difference between semantics of `IO` and `ST` related to that there is one `IO` and many independent `ST`, but I'm not sure.

```
> runST (newSTRef True)

<interactive>:5:8: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘STRef s Bool’
        because type variable ‘s’ would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall s. ST s a
        at <interactive>:5:1-21
      Expected type: ST s a
        Actual type: ST s (STRef s Bool)
    • In the first argument of ‘runST’, namely ‘(newSTRef True)’
      In the expression: runST (newSTRef True)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = runST (newSTRef True)
    • Relevant bindings include it :: a (bound at <interactive>:5:1)

> :t newSTRef
newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)

> :t runST
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

Comment: my understanding of `ST` is, think of it like a universe. every `ST` operations might turn one universe into another(by mutation). that's why `ST` can be turned into `IO` by tagging it with `RealWorld`. so your question is really the same as asking if `IO` is pure or not.

Comment: Every value of type `forall s . ST s A` is referentially transparent, just like every value of type `IO A` is referentially transparent (since such values are computations representing how to produce the resulting value, not the value itself). While `ST s (STRef s A)` can't be `run`, it is still a valid computation; e.g. you can apply a function of type `STRef s A -> ST s B` to get `forall s . ST s B` which can be run. However, I'm not actually sure what the question is - why do you think the code in question should be allowed? (note: "I don't really understand why" is a poor explanation)

Comment: `ST` allows dynamic allocated memory, and pointers/references to such memory. It is designed so that all the memory could, in principle, be freed at the end of `runST`. For that, it is vital that no pointer can escape `runST`. Such escaped pointers would also cause weird effects related to evaluation ordering, e.g. `f (runST $ writeSTRef r True) + g (runST $ readSTRef r)` could evaluate to different results depending on which `runST` is evaluated first. Referential transparency is meant to avoid such ordering issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More an answer to the question title than the question itself, but still:

Yes, ST is referentially transparent.

For a long time this was just conjectured and believed, and only this year we have a proper proof for that:

**A Logical Relation for Monadic Encapsulation of State: Proving contextual equivalences in the presence of runST**
Amin Timany, Léo Stefanesco, Morten Krogh-Jespersen, Lars Birkedal
 
Conditionally accepted to POPL 2018
http://iris-project.org/ [Preprint PDF](http://iris-project.org/pdfs/2018-popl-runST-submission.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

I don't really understand what you're asking, so I'm going to pretend your question is:

> Why is ST designed to disallow `runST (newSTRef True)`?

If that were allowed, it would no longer be referentially transparent:

```
main = do
    let r = runST (newSTRef True)
    evaluate (runST (writeSTRef r False))
    print (runST (readSTRef r))
```

This code would output `False`.

```
main = do
    evaluate (runST (writeSTRef (runST (newSTRef True)) False))
    print (runST (readSTRef (runST (newSTRef True))))
```

This code (the result of inlining `r` in every user) would output `True`, because each instance of `runST (newSTRef True)` would allocate a new `STRef` variable.

The way `runST` is actually implemented ensures that all resources allocated within an `ST s` action cannot escape that action.

The difference between `IO` and `ST s` is that there is no `runIO` function. You can create multiple independent `IO` actions, but they don't matter without `runIO` (they're just values). The only way to actually run an `IO` action is to bind it to `main` and let the runtime system pick it up (it's like there's a single implicit `runIO` wrapped around `main`), so there's only one single `IO` action that will ever get executed in a program.

Of course this single action can be composed by combining multiple smaller actions, but in the end it's still a monolith. On the other hand, `runST` allows multiple `ST s` actions to be executed independently.

Comment: I realized that my question touches a more complex subject than I had anticipated and I admit that it's unclear. But this answer gives me (and hopefully others) some clue. Initially, I had incorrectly assumed that `ST s a` would break referential transparency when `a = STRef s x` because this `a` mixes real references in pure code! But the existential type seems to be crucial in enforcing correctness of `runST`. This part I find the most difficult to understand and it feels like it is a very clever invention (or discovery).